# SRID error in mapserver

Tags: coordinate-system, mapserver

I've created a network topology using QGIS, saved it as a shp, imported it into PostGIS using shp2pgsql and I'm now trying to output some of the geometry using mapserver.

Unfortunately mapserver is kicking up the following error:

> msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'ROUTE'.
>   msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Query error. Error (**ERROR: Operation on
>   two geometries with different SRIDs** ) executing query: select
>   encode(AsBinary(force_collection(force_2d("the_geom")),'NDR'),'hex')
>   as geom,"gid" from (SELECT buildingroute.the_geom,buildingroute.gid
>   FROM routetest INNER JOIN buildingroute ON
>   routetest.toid=buildingroute.gid ORDER BY routetest.id ASC) AS foo
>   where the_geom && GeomFromText('POLYGON((-22000000 -11000000,-22000000
>   11000000,22000000 11000000,22000000 -11000000,-22000000
>   -11000000))',32709)

Now I don't know a lot about spatial referencing, but I've copied the settings from QGIS and I still get those errors. Here's those settings in QGIS:
[image]

The mapserver file I created can be found at http://pastie.org/2202322

If anyone can give me advice on what I need to change in the mapserver file I'd appreciate it.. I expect I've just got the projection settings wrong..

Thanks!

Comment: To be sure of your projection, you should check your tables srid : *SELECT srid(the_geom) FROM "routetest" LIMIT 1* and *SELECT srid(the_geom) FROM "buildingroute" LIMIT 1*

Comment: Unless you explicitly set the SRID during conversion in `shp2pgsql`, I think it defaults to -1, which is the "unknown" projection.

Comment: Excellent point.. I tried those queries and it reported that the SRID was -1. I used MerseyViking's technique to change the SRID and that fixed that issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your map file try changing the map's projection to read from the epsg file. Your current map projection isn't a full projection description.

So rather than:

```
MAP
    NAME TEST
    STATUS ON
    IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
    IMAGETYPE PNG
    PROJECTION
      "proj=utm"
      "ellps=WGS84"
      "datum=WGS84"
    END
```

Use:

```
MAP
    NAME TEST
    STATUS ON
    IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
    IMAGETYPE PNG
    PROJECTION
      "init=epsg:32709"
    END
```

Or put in the full projection description of:

```
PROJECTION
  "proj=utm"
  "ellps=WGS84"
  "datum=WGS84"
  "zone=9"
  "units=m"
  "south"
  "no_defs"
END
```

As your layer is in the same projection as the map you can remove the projection from the layer definition - it is assumed to be in the map projeciton unless specified otherwise.

```
   PROJECTION
      "init=epsg:32709"
   END
```

Comment: Along with having the wrong projection in the database this did the trick nicely. Thanks! I really need to learn more about mapserver as it seems very powerful - unfortunately I'm quite new to GIS and projections though so it seems like quite a steep learning curve.