# Query failed: ERROR: Operation on two geometries with different SRID

Tags: pgrouting

Following the pgRouting workshop [here](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/php_server.html), I have the routing query below:

```sql
$sql = "SELECT gid, start_id AS source, end_id AS target, the_geom, 
                  distance(the_geom, GeometryFromText(
                       'POINT(".$lonlat[0]." ".$lonlat[1].")', 4326)) AS dist 
                 FROM ".TABLE."  
                 WHERE the_geom && setsrid(
                       'BOX3D(".($lonlat[0]-0.1)." 
                              ".($lonlat[1]-0.1).", 
                              ".($lonlat[0]+0.1)." 
                              ".($lonlat[1]+0.1).")'::box3d, 4326) 
                 ORDER BY dist LIMIT 1";
```

This query fails with the error: `Query failed: ERROR:  Operation on two geometries with different SRIDs`. Now, I've been looking around and came across [this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-4442). I've tried the suggestions on this post, but the error persists. Any idea on how to fix this will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** 
Running `SELECT st_srid(the_geom) FROM table_name` against my database table returns `-1`. In my query and map, the assumed external projection is `EPSG:4326`. Is changing this value likely to help? Is there any harm in changing the srid value directly in the database? How can I go about changing the srid value in the database if it doesn't present any risk?

**UPDATE:**
I had to change the srid of the column from the `UNKNOWN` indicator of `-1` to `4326`. The answer at this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012723/how-to-change-srid-of-geometry-column) was very helpful in this. Also, the question in this [SE GIS post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12078/srid-error-in-mapserver) was instrumental in helping me in the right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to change the srid of the column from the `UNKNOWN` indicator of `-1` to `4326`. The answer at this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012723/how-to-change-srid-of-geometry-column) was very helpful in this. Also, the question in this [SE GIS post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12078/srid-error-in-mapserver) was instrumental in helping me in the right direction.

Summarily: Running `UPDATE table_name SET the_geom = ST_SetSRID(the_geom, 4326)` and `UPDATE table_name SET the_geom = ST_Transform(the_geom, 4326)` did it.

Comment: For some reason I had to do a `VACUUM ANALYZE table_name` after this to really get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in okello's answer: the two commands should be in inverted order. It's `UPDATE table_name SET the_geom = ST_Transform(the_geom, 4326)` first, to do the conversion, and then `UPDATE table_name SET the_geom = ST_SetSRID(the_geom, 4326)` to tell PostGIS that the new values are to be interpreted as WGS84.