# ST_Intersects throws an error on mixed SRIDs that && permits

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapserver

I found that there is a difference in result between using `A && B` operator or one of the geo functions like `ST_Intersects(A,B)`

While the `ST_Intersects` functions return query results without errors the operator version SOMETIMES results in errors over the SRID:

> ERROR:  Operation on two geometries with different SRID's.
>
> ERROR: Operation on two geometries with different SRIDs
>   SQL state: XX000

All of the records seem have the correct SRID, none missing.

The query is generated by MAPSERV WMS server, so what is there to do?

Sample query:

- Operator `&&`

  ```
  select encode(AsBinary(force_collection(force_2d("geometry")),'NDR'),'hex') as geom, "id" 
  from (select * from soils.vw_zones) as vw
  where geometry && GeomFromText('POLYGON((75722.1945223652   437331.342330005,75722.1945223652 503295.946741193,169438.897876772 503295.946741193,169438.897876772 437331.342330005,75722.1945223652 437331.342330005))',find_srid('','soils.vw_zones','geometry'))
  ```
- `ST_Intersects`

  ```
  select encode(AsBinary(force_collection(force_2d("geometry")),'NDR'),'hex') as geom, "id" 
  from (select * from soils.vw_zones) as vw
  where st_intersects(geometry,GeomFromText('POLYGON((75722.1945223652 437331.342330005,75722.1945223652 503295.946741193,169438.897876772 503295.946741193,169438.897876772 437331.342330005,75722.1945223652 437331.342330005))',find_srid('','soils.vw_zones','geometry')))
  ```

Comment: When I have tested && and ST_Intersects before, the && version just compares bounding boxes. So it is very quick but in a way not that accurate.

Where as the ST_Intersect does a bounding box to reduce the number of features to check against, and then does a full geometry check feature against feature.

Comment: It's not clear what this question about, the answer is about the difference between the two, the question is about error-generation on the two and has nothing to do with the answer.

Answer (score 9):

- [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) checks if 2 geometry really intersects
- [&&](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html) checks if the BBox of both geometries intersect. This use only the index if available. That's why it is really really fast.

For the SRID error look at this answer:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/12082/22703

Comment: I don't thin this answers the question at all. It just documents some of the unrelated differences.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is addressed in [#2320: "Operator && does not detect mixed SRIDs"](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2320),

PostGIS's Regina says

> This has always been an issue from the beginning of time and not one that is easy to fix. **Boxes simply don't have srids so to add a check like that would significantly slow things down. `&&` work on the boxes of geometries and in fact usually just touch the index if there is one and rarely the geometry.**

There is a simple test case of that too on the ticket.

Earlier you can find it mentioned on [#520: "No check for different srid on operators when index is used"](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/520), again Regina says,

> FWIW, I really don't think this is a big issue and would just assume forget about it if its hard to fix. Usually when people use &&, they know what they are doing and I suspect trying to fix this will just slow things down. NOTE: This more common query does give error: [query at link above demonstrating `ST_Intersects`]

Comment: That's a really useful bit of info.